# Throttle outgoing connection to external API

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm currently developing website in asp core 2.2. This site use external API. But I have one big problem and don't know how to solve this. This external API has limit 10 reguest per IP/s. If 11 user click button on my site and call API at the same time, the API can cut me off for a couple hours. The API owner tells clients to take care of not exceeding the limit. Can you have any idea how doing this?

[image: 1]

ps. Of course, a million users are a joke, but I want the site to be publicly available :)

Comment: How likely is it that the limit will be reached soon. Does every visit to your site mean a call to that api. And then once, twice or...? What would be an acceptable wait time if the limit is reached?

Comment: Not every visit. Client must type company ID number to get some information from the government database. But I want to give the opportunity type multiple numer at once. I think to make some wait respond. But i dont know how to manage connection from multiple client.

Answer (score 2):

That 10 request/s is a hard limit and it seems like theres no way around it. So you have to solve it on your end.

There are couple options:

1. Calls that API directly using Javascript. This way each user will be able to do 10 request/s instead of 10 request/s for all users  (recommended)
2. Queue the requests and only send out at most 10/s (highly not recommended, kills your thread pool and can block everyone from accessing your site when the speed of input coming is > output)
3. Drop the request on server side when you are reaching that 10/s limit and have the client retry at a later time. (wait time will be infinite when speed of input coming is > output)

And depending on the content returned by the API you might be able to cache it on server side to avoid having to request it from the 3rd party again.

Comment: I recommend adding a comment about caching. Depending on what the public API is, it might be possible to cache the response in your own app, so you don't need to make requests to the public API for each incoming request.

Comment: Thx. The first option is interesting. I'll check it!

Comment: Scaling out could be an (potentially expensive) option as well.

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario you would need to account for the possibility that you can't process requests in real time. You wouldn't want to have thousands of requests waiting on access to a resource that you don't control.

I second the answer about calling the API from the client, if that's an option.

Another option is to keep a counter of current requests, limit it to ten, and return a 503 error if a request comes in that exceeds that capacity. That's practical if you really don't expect to exceed ten concurrent requests often or ever but want to be sure that in the odd chance that it happens it doesn't shut down this feature of your site.

If you actually expect large volumes where you would exceed ten concurrent requests then you would need to queue the requests, but do it in a process separate from your web application. As mentioned, if you have tons of requests waiting for the same resource your application will become overloaded. You could enqueue the request with an entirely different process, and then the client would have to poll your application with occasional requests to see if there's a response.

The big flaw in this last scenario is that it means your users could end up waiting a long time because your application depends on a finite resource that you cannot scale. You can manage it in a way that keeps your application from failing, but not in a way that makes it respond quickly.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's interesting.

Comment: One option could be to have the process reading the queue deliver the result by email or something, if that is acceptable.

Comment: That crossed my mind. What I like about that question is it forces you to think about how long someone might actually be willing to wait for whatever it is that the site is going to do for them, and how long you're willing to make them wait. Will they be willing to wait for an email? I think if the answer is yes then you're onto something huge, and before long you'll be able to duplicate the service you're depending on, pay for more concurrent requests, or just buy it.